# exception in mvc 5, model is not passing data in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
  public ActionResult CustomerOrders()
    {
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName; //Find cookie name
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName]; //Get the cookie by it's name
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value); //Decrypt it
        string UserName = ticket.Name;
        int UserID = context.Registers.Where(x => x.name == UserName).Select(x => x.id).FirstOrDefault();

       var data = (from i in context.Registers.Where(x => x.id == UserID)
                             join
                              c in context.Orders on i.id equals c.customer_id
                             into egroup
                             from k in egroup
                             join p in context.Products
                             on k.product_id equals p.product_id
                             select new
                             {
                                 p.price,
                                 // k.order_total,
                                 p.ImageUrl,
                                 p.ProductName

                             }).ToList() ;
        Products pr = new Products();

        return View(data);
       // return View(data);
    }
```

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`3[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PetsApplication.Models.Products]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory! In your LINQ expression, you are projecting the result to a list of annonymous objects and passing that to the view. But your view is strongly typed to a collection of `Products` class.

Change your anonymous object projection to the projection using `Product` class.

```
var data = (from i in context.Registers.Where(x => x.id == UserID)
            join c in context.Orders on i.id equals c.customer_id
            into egroup
            from k in egroup
            join p in context.Products
            on k.product_id equals p.product_id
            select new Products
            {
                price=p.price,                   
                ImageUrl=p.ImageUrl,
                ProductName=p.ProductName

            }).ToList();
 return View(data);
```

Comment: I am facing this exception now.The entity or complex type 'model.Products' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Comment: Do you have an entity class named `Products` ?

Comment: @model  PetsApplication.Models.Products

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustomerOrders";
}

<h2>CustomerOrders</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Products</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
        </dd>

        <dt>

Comment: Your view is strongly typed to a collection of `Products` or a single instance. From your question, it looks like it is a collection and now you are saying it is a single instance.

Comment: my issue not resolved , now i am getting this exception

Comment: You need to provide clear information. For your error, I asked "Do you have an entity class named `Products`". If not, change the class name according to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is strongly typed and you are passing the Anonymous Type create a class of list item and then use it as view Model to pass the data to view.